# omegle.com title change imitation

Tags: javascript, html, timeout, title

I was looking at `omegle.com` and noticed that when someone is typing, the title changes every half second from `--Omegle--` to `__Omegle__` or something similar. Is this in JavaScript? If so, how would I recreate something like this? No - NOT for homework. Just thought it was cool.

EDIT: I got it to happen once but I can't figure out how i would get it to occur regularly without a `while(1 == 1)` thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in javascript

change document.title every half second

change the icon? i have never try .i will try it justnow!wait!
i have try it ! but i can't achieve it!

Comment: do you, by any chance, know if images can go in the page title?

Answer (score 0):

They use a function which is called periodically by the browser in order to alter the `document.title`, using [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval).

Comment: You know....figures. The second after I solve this, someone answers. I just used two functions which call each other after .5 seconds.